# Trying to create sub menu using HTML5 and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and though I would ask help from the internet. I would like to create a sub-menu which appears when i hover over the link. This part of it works to a fashion, but when the links appear on the webpage, they are completely unformatted. Any help or advice would I would be extremely grateful for.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c1zcj78t/)

Thanks in advance.

**HTML code**

```
<body>

        <nav>
        <ul><li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>      

        <li><a href="#">venue</a>
        <ul class="hidden"> <li><a href="venue.html">address</a></li>
        <li><a href="venue.html#background">venue background</a></li>
        <li><a href="venue.html#instructors">instructors</a></li></ul> </li>

        <li><a href="wakeboarding.html">wakeboarding</a>
        <ul class="hidden"> <li><a href="wakeboarding.html">background</a></li> 
        <li><a href="wakeboarding.html">future</a></li></ul> </li>

        <li><a href="events.html">up-coming events</a>
        <ul class="hidden"> <li><a href="events.html">professional</a></li> 
        <li><a href="events.html">amateur</a></li> </ul></li>

        <li><a href="prices.html">prices</a>
        <ul class="hidden"> <li><a href="prices.html">prices</a></li> 
        <li><a href="events.html">special offers</a></li></ul> </li>

        <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li></ul>
        </nav>

        <img src = "logo.png"
         alt = "Logo" />

        <form>
            <input type="email" required placeholder="sign up for newsletter" /> <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
<br />
```

**CSS code**

```
body nav > ul >  li {

list-style-type: none;
position: intial;
top: 110px;
//right: -200px;
display: inline;

}

body nav > ul .hidden   {


opacity: 1;
position: relative;

}

body nav > ul > li:hover  >.hidden  {

visibility: visible;
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:10x;

}



body nav ul li  {

display: inline;
padding: 80px;
font-family: Geneva,Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; 
font-size: 24px; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look to this if it helps you

> https://jsfiddle.net/Edrees21/ae55p7u1/2/

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="main-menu-item">
            <a class="link">Link 1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub menu 1</li>
                <li>Sub menu 2</li>
                <li>Sub menu 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-item">
            <a class="link">Link 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub menu 1</li>
                <li>Sub menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-item">
            <a class="link">Link 3</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>Sub menu 1</li>
                <li>Sub menu 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

```
li {
    padding: 5px;
}

.main-menu-item {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.main-menu-item:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 80px;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, looks perfect for what I need :D